# Pulling a value from one jQuery function into another

Tags: jquery, cookies, color-picker

I'm trying to take the hex value chosen from a jQuery colorpicker plugin, and store it as a cookie using the jQuery cookie plugin.

I just don't know the appropriate way to tie the two together (new to js and jQuery).

Here's my colorpicker function:

```
    $('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
color: '#ffffff',
onShow: function (colpkr) {
    $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
    return false;
},
onHide: function (colpkr) {
    $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
    return false;
},
onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
    $('#colorSelector div, .preview-image, .cover ').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
    $('body').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
        $.cookie('bgColor', 'picker');
    return false;
}
});
```

And here's my cookie function as is:

```
    var bgColor = $.cookie('bgColor');  

if (bgColor == 'picker') {  
$('#colorSelector div, .preview-image, .cover ').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);  
};
```

I can set and store the cookie value as a standard css background-color, but can't figure out how to pull the "'backgroundColor', '#' + hex" value into the cookie function.

Comment: So is the value of bgColor == 'picker' in your cookie function?

Comment: The value of 'picker' isn't in the cookie function, just the colorSelector function (by default) = 'backgroundColor', '#' + hex

I can't figure out how to pull that value from one function to the other.

Answer (score 0):

in onChange function:

```
$.cookie('bgColor', '#' + hex);
```

and in cookie function

```
var bgColor = $.cookie('bgColor');      
if (typeof bgColor == 'string' && bgColor.charAt(0)=='#') {  
  $('#colorSelector div, .preview-image, .cover ').css('backgroundColor', bgColor);  
};
```

Comment: I apologize, left that digg text in from testing.  Edited it to reflect the same name in both functions, 'picker'.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, any chance you could paste a revised version of my code with your suggestion function, so I can see how it would work? Thanks, Pier.

Answer (score 0):

Change the body selector for your needs.

```
    (function($){



    var initLayout = function() {
        var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
        var currentTab = $('ul.navigationTabs a')
                            .bind('click', showTab)
                            .filter('a[rel=' + hash + ']');
        if (currentTab.size() == 0) {
            currentTab = $('ul.navigationTabs a:first');
        }
        showTab.apply(currentTab.get(0));
        $('#colorpickerHolder').ColorPicker({flat: true});
        $('#colorpickerHolder2').ColorPicker({
            flat: true,
            color: '#00ff00',
            onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb) {
                $('#colorSelector2 div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
            }
        });
        $('#colorpickerHolder2>div').css('position', 'absolute');
        var widt = false;
        $('#colorSelector2').bind('click', function() {
            $('#colorpickerHolder2').stop().animate({height: widt ? 0 : 173}, 500);
            widt = !widt;
        });
        $('#colorpickerField1, #colorpickerField2, #colorpickerField3').ColorPicker({
            onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
                $(el).val(hex);
                $(el).ColorPickerHide();
            },
            onBeforeShow: function () {
                $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
            }
        })
        .bind('keyup', function(){
            $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
        });

            var bgColor = $.cookie('bgColor');      
            if (typeof bgColor == 'string' && bgColor.charAt(0)=='#') {  
            $('body').css('backgroundColor', bgColor);  
            };


        $('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
            color: '#0000ff',
            onShow: function (colpkr) {
                $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
                return false;
            },
            onHide: function (colpkr) {
                $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
                return false;
            },
            onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
            $('body').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
            $.cookie('bgColor', '#' + hex);
            }


        });
    };

    var showTab = function(e) {
        var tabIndex = $('ul.navigationTabs a')
                            .removeClass('active')
                            .index(this);
        $(this)
            .addClass('active')
            .blur();
        $('div.tab')
            .hide()
                .eq(tabIndex)
                .show();
    };

    EYE.register(initLayout, 'init');
})(jQuery)
```